# ng build --prod => Error: Unknown argument: prod

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I try to build my angular project in production environment:

```
ng build --prod --aot
```

the console returns this error:

```
Error: Unknown argument: prod
```

`ng serve` is working fine and `ng build` without parameters seems to work too. Why does angular return such an error?

Answer (score 278, accepted):

The reason for this error is
the command `--prod` is **deprecated since Angular 12 and removed in Angular 14**
based on this [Angular-Deprecated APIs and features](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularcli).

Use `--configuration production` instead.

So the command will be:

```
ng build --configuration production
```

Comment: YSK VS2022's Angular template still uses --prod but it also has Angular 13. If you update to 14 or bring your own Angular 14 project you can update the --prod in the .csproj file. Double clicking the "Unknown argument: prod" error will take you right to the liune to change.

Comment: you think that might have deserved a mention in the official update guide...

Comment: In my case Error: Invalid values:
  Argument: project, Given: "dev", Choices: "demoProjectName" showing... "ng build --configuration production dev" this command i am using

Comment: @SureshPanigrahi you cannot have 2 configurations at the same time, production and dev are 2 separate configs that should be declared in the angular.json file, check that file and see the options in there is all. and to be more clear 
"ng build --configuration production" builds for production environment
"ng build --configuration dev" (if defined in the angular.json correctly like that) will build for the development environment.

Comment: By default, the ng build command uses the production configuration (https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#build-target)

Answer (score 42):

`ng build --configuration production --aot` can help.

Answer (score 30):

I had the same issue with the ***--prod*** command, below is the reason it's not working.

[image]

Ref: https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularcli

New command: **ng build --configuration production**

> Another way you can add this command in the script section in your package.json

Now just run **npm run build-prod**

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Since **Angular 15** `ng build` is similar to `ng build --configuration production`

[image]

Comment: including.....?

Answer (score 7):

you can also use:

```
ng build -c production
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem because recently updated angular version from 12 to 15 and when I build on Azure Dev Ops Pipeline, I was getting error

```
from <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />
to <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build --prod" />
```

In csprog file.

Comment: What does "the *from* part" mean, what "the *to* part"?

Comment: I have updated the csprog file , it was <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />

Comment: So `-- --prod` didn't work any more, but changing that to `--prod` made the message not appear?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when deploying a legacy Angular solution contained in a .Net project via a Devops pipeline, after updating to Node v20.x.

The fix was to edit the .csproj file to update the `Command` attribute from the old version, which was this:

```html
<!-- OLD -->
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />
```

To the new syntax, which is this:

```html
<!-- NEW -->
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --configuration production" />
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --configuration production" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />
```

Note the change of `--prod` to `--configuration production`.