# Azure devops pipeline - your global CLI version is greater than your local

Tags: angular, azure, npm, azure-devops

So I'm trying to deploy an angular front end to Azure pipeline from GitHub, which uses yaml. However, the job fails at the npm build and install stage, saying 'Your global Angular CLI version (15.2.6) is greater than your local version (15.0.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.'
Any idea how i'd resolve this issue?

screenshot for context:
[image]

Comment: The CLI version mismatch is just a warning. Your problem might be sending an unknown argument `prod`. perhaps you are looking for something in the line of `--configuration production` instead. `ng build --prod` is deprecated in angular 12 and removed in 14.

Comment: Enable diagnostics and run your pipeline again for the detailed error?

Answer (score 0):

> 'Your global Angular CLI version (15.2.6) is greater than your local version (15.0.4). The local Angular CLI version is used

As @Nils Kähler mentioned, this is just a warning; It won't affect your application from running/ building successfully.

But I can see you are getting error:

> Error: Unknown argument: prod
> ##[error] Bash exited with code `1`.

***It is mentioned in the official [document](https://v14.angular.io/guide/deprecations#deprecated-cli-apis-and-options) that `--prod` is deprecated in v14 and later versions.***

[image]
Hence, It is recommended to use

```js
ng build --configuration production
```

as a fix instead of

```js
ng build --prod
```

you can also include command `"build-prod":"ng build --configuration production"` in your script in package.json as mentioned in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73156911/ng-build-prod-error-unknown-argument-prod) by *Abdullah*.

[image]

> 'Your global Angular CLI version (15.2.6) is greater than your local version (15.0.4). The local Angular CLI version is used

To avoid this warning: First, delete package-lock.json file node_modules then proceed to uninstall the existing version and install latest version of the Angular CLI by running the below commands as mentioned in [Document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli/v/1.6.0):

**Locally:**

```js
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

**Globally:**

```js
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

*Command to check updated Angular cli version:*

```
ng version
```